# TableView only loading visible cells (top 4 sections out of 12 section table view)

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, autolayout

I'm trying to figure out why my tableView is only rendering sections that are visible to the user when the viewDidAppear method is called.

When I first launch the application, sections 1, 2, and 3 render correctly as seen below. However, sections 4 and later don't render correctly. When I press the refresh button (manually calling the reload() method), the visible sections during the time of clicking the refresh button refresh and render correctly.

I have linked my viewDidAppear method, as well as a temporary "Refresh" button, to the reload() method below:

```
    textViewArray = [m1DF,m2DF,m3DF,m4DF,m5DF,m6DF,m7DF,m8DF,m9DF,m10DF,m11DF,m12DF,m13DF,m14DF,m15DF,m16DF]

    for (index, tv) in textViewArray!.enumerate() {
        let fixedWidth = tv.frame.size.width
        tv.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
        let newSize = tv.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
        var newFrame = tv.frame
        newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
        tv.frame = newFrame;
        heightArray[index] = newSize.height
    }

    for (index, _) in (heightArray.enumerate()) {
        heightArray[index] = textViewArray![index].frame.height

    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

When I first launch the application, sections 1, 2, and 3 render correctly as seen below:

[image]

However, sections 4 and later don't render correctly:
[image]

When I press the refresh button (manually calling the reload() method), the visible sections during the time of clicking the refresh button (in this case, sections titled "M05" and "M06") refresh and render correctly:

[image]

**EDIT**

Full code excluding outlets:

import UIKit
import AdSupport
import iAd

```
class CalculatorTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var heightArray: [CGFloat] = [44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0,44.0]

    var textViewArray = [UITextView]?()

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        reload()
    }



    func reload() {

        textViewArray = [m1DF,m2DF,m3DF,m4DF,m5DF,m6DF,m7DF,m8DF,m9DF,m10DF,m11DF,m12DF,m13DF,m14DF,m15DF,m16DF]
        print("*****1*****\n\n\n\n\n \(m1DF.bounds.height), \(m1DF.frame.height)")

        for (index, tv) in textViewArray!.enumerate() {
            let fixedWidth = tv.frame.size.width
            tv.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
            let newSize = tv.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
            var newFrame = tv.frame
            newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
            tv.frame = newFrame;
            heightArray[index] = newSize.height
            print("Row \(index) has height \(newSize.height)")
        }

        for (index, _) in (heightArray.enumerate()) {
            heightArray[index] = textViewArray![index].frame.height

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        //sizeCell(indexPath.section)
    }

    @IBAction func refreshButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        reload()



    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 300.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return heightArray[indexPath.section]
        } else {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
    }

    /*override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200.0
    }*/



}
```

Comment: @vikingsegundo what do you mean by that?

Comment: If you would check the documentation you would find that table views is designed to only render visible cells. Why should it do an likely expensive rendering for cells that maybe never will be shown? Your issues come from not correctly implementing data source and delegate.

Comment: My problem is that it's not rendering the cells below even AFTER they're clearly visible to the user. THey're only rendering when i FORCE them to render using the refresh button.

Comment: as I said: you have issues in your data source and delegate. and guess what: We can't help you as long you don't show the code.

Comment: Added my code above...

Comment: if you put breakpoints into this methods, you should be able to figure out, what is happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123080/discussion-between-albert-ghar-and-vikingosegundo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking through your code, I think you are getting confused over the key principles of implementing a table view in UIKit. It can be intimidating and I certainly found it confusing at first! You should look through the reference at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView
This outlines in more detail a number of things I'm about to talk about.
Essentially, a UiTableViewController needs to do two things: first, it needs to know where to get the data from to populate the tables; and second, it needs to know how to put the table together in the way you want and present it to the user. 
For the first of these tasks - call it the data task, it's actually quite easy. You just need to ensure the table view controller has access to a data object which encapsulates all the data you need. There is a dedicated protocol for this too - UITableViewDataSource - but you don't need to be this sophisticated. I've implemented tables with anything from arrays of strings to using dedicated data manager classes working in much higher dimensions.

The second of these tasks - call it the presentation task - can be the more confusing. The way in which you configure your table view is via delegate methods which come ready packaged with the UITableViewController object (as it is the table view's delegate by default).

Perhaps the most important of these is: cellForRowAtIndexPath:. This function tells the view what to put at each index path in the table. You use the index path provided in the delegate function to locate the data you need (for instance, cell.text = stringData[indexPath.row] in a simple case) and you then tailor the view and any subviews to present that data as you would want to. I'm assuming you know how to do this. One thing that can be problematic with implementing cellForRowAtIndexPath: is that you need to re-use a dequeued cell rather than creating a new cell every time you need one. The way you do this is: first, tell the table view controller which class you are using for your reusable cells with a call to registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier. In the standard case the class you would register would be UiTableViewCell, but you can use your own too. You can then grab one of these cells (which will be a cell that is no longer being used, I.e. It has scrolled off the screen) with a call to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.

The other key function that you will need is: numberOfRowsInSection(_ section: Int) which tells the controller how many rows in each section of the table (if there's only one section it is of course the number of rows in the table). You use this with the UITableView variable numberOfSections and UITableView rowHeight when initializing the table to set these basic parameters.

Putting this all together, there is no need to set the height for each row in the table (as the array you have used apears to be trying to do), nor to have an explicit reload() function - there is a function "built in" to do this which simply calls the methods I have already alluded to.

For the sake of not making this one of the longest posts I've written I'll leave it there! However, if you'd like me to send over some sample code I'd be happy to do so, although it's probably better for you to play around with what I've briefly outlined above - hope that helps!